# Inconsistent "Required type: byte provided: int" in Java

Tags: java, int, byte

I stored integers in byte arrays but suddenly i got a "Required type: byte   provided: int" error and some lines above not. So i tried to find out what different was, tests below:

```
    byte b;
    int integer = 12;
    final int finalInteger = 12;
    final int finalIntegerLO = 128; // 1000 0000

    b = integer;               //Required type byte provided int
    b = finalInteger;          //OK
    b = finalIntegerLO;        //Required type byte provided int
```

I guess having a final int with no '1' in the 2^7 place is Ok? It gave me an idea what happens if you combine it with bitwise operators and now it makes much less sense to me..

```
    b = finalIntegerLO & 0xf;  //OK
```

Is now ok..
but

```
    b = integer & 0xf;         //Required type byte provided int
```

not??

Can someone explain me why it acts so different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break every line

---

## case 1:

```java
b = integer
```

Here we can see we are trying to convert `int` into a `byte`, so compiler asks as to explicitly typecast like so. (value of `integer` may exceed byte range.)

```java
b = (byte) integer;
```

---

## case 2:

```java
b = finalInteger;
```

This case is slightly different since `finalInteger` is a constant whose value is fixed and the compiler can tell beforehand whether it lies within the range of byte or not. If it lies within the range compiler is smart enough to convert `int` to `byte` without us to explicitly typecast it.

---

## case 3:

```java
b = finalIntegerLO;
```

Range of byte is `-128 to 127` clearly we cannot convert int to a byte and compiler sees that `finalIntegerLO` is a constant so it is impossible to carry out this conversion and we see an error

To remove this error we can explicitly typecase (**DONT DO IT THOUGH**) which will give use as `b = -128`

```
b = (byte) finalIntegerLO;
```

---

## case 4:

```java
b = finalIntegerLO & 0xf;
```

Here `finalIntegerLO` and `0xf` both are constants and compiler can determine what will be the result it's `0` which is within the range of byte.

---

## case 5:

```java
b = integer & 0xf;
```

Here `integer` value can be changed before the execution of this line so the compiler is not sure if the result is within the range of `int` or not, so it asks us to explicitly typecast like so.

```java
b = (byte) (integer & 0xf);
```

Again like **case 3** you may get an unexpected result.

Comment: Ok thank you. I didn't thought the compiler is so 'smart' ^^

Answer (score 0):

The error that is received while executing b = integer is "*incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte*". When this statement is being executed by the compiler, an implicit type conversion from a *higher data type(int)* to a *lower data type(byte)* is being carried out. This is not possible as there *might* be loss of information/precision with such conversions and hence, java tried to avoid them. An alternative would be to force/coerce the conversion using an explicit type conversion as follows:

```
byte b;
int integer = 12;
b = (byte) integer;
```

Moving on,

```
final int finalInteger = 12;
final int finalIntegerLO = 128;
```

b = finalInteger works because the *final* keyword ensures that the variable *finalInteger* does not change its value. Since, we are already telling our Java compiler that we cannot change the value of *finalInteger* variable and because *finalInteger* stores a value that is in the range of values that can be stored in a byte variable (-128 to 127), the conversion from *int* to *byte* is possible.
*b = finalIntegerLO* does not work because the value of *finalIntegerLO* exceeds the maximum value for a byte variable, i.e, -128 to 127.